# Chruby and RVM I don't recall ever installing Chruby, but I'm consistently getting this message chruby: unknown Ruby: ruby-2.3.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm, chruby

I've done some reading here and I'm not sure I understand the distinction or the necessity of Chruby if I already have RVM. I don't ever remember specifically installing it and the more I read about it the more I'm confused by what it actually is supposed to do for me.

I recently re-installed RVM and updated to Ruby 2.3.3 which is when I started seeing the `chruby: unknown Ruby: ruby-2.3.3` warning. As I read about Chruby, if I'm understanding this correctly, it holds the same function as RVM in that it switches between rubies, however, it does not install them.

What I don't understand is if RVM can do both of those things why do I need Chruby and why should it also be installed at the same time as RVM? Is there some sort of conflict between the two similarly functioning pieces of software over who is in charge of setting the current ruby? How did it get on my system? Should I do something about chruby and/or rvm?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `chruby` if you have `rvm` or `rbenv`.

I would consider uninstalling `chruby` & `rvm` (and any other ruby version manager that may be lurking around on your system) and go for a fresh install of `rvm` or `rbenv`

https://rvm.io/workflow/chruby (how rvm and chruby are supposed to run side-by-side)
https://github.com/postmodern/chruby#uninstall (how to uninstall chruby)